# Model View Controller is breaking my stylesheet links

Tags: css, model-view-controller, restful-authentication

I'm trying to create a website using Bootstrap Studio and I'm using a Model View Controller with a RESTful API as middleware. When I test my HTML file for the frontend locally, in its folder, it loads as expected. However when I save it into the XAmpp folder and try to load the page as a view through the Index page, it breaks and I get this error in the console: "GET http://localhost/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

I have tried to move the assets folder into my view folder, I've tried changing the file path in my HTML when loading the CSS files. I've also added 'type = "text/css"' as that was causing a different issue. I've tried looking to look up an answer for myself, and read that because of the middleware, it's trying to authorise the CSS on a page that's also trying to get authorization?  However, the thread didn't offer a solution or a workaround...

.htmacces file

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Example of the CSS call

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="../assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Everything works as expected until I try and load the page through the MVC model which redirects all requests to my index page, then loads a view depending on what URL is attached.

Comment: So looking into it further... it would see I need to add routing for a static folder where all my assets are found. Apprently I can do this with 
```app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/bin/index.html');
```

However, I'm not quite sure where to add this or how the syntax works... Getting closer tho!! :D

Comment: Supposing that your file system structure is something like `/path/to/public/assets/...`, then you should write your references to the client-side assets like this: `<link href="/assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css" ...>` and this: `<img src="/assets/images/logo.png"... />` and this: `<script src="/assets/js/custom.js" ...></script>`.

Comment: As an alternative, in your web server config file you could define an alias for your `assets` folder, like this: `Alias "/assets/" "/path/to/assets/" <Directory "/path/to/assets">Require all granted</Directory>`. Then, in your mvc, you would access your assets exactly as I wrote in the previous comment.